# Uncaught exception - NSRangeException

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsrangeexception

I've been trying to sort out this error I keep getting with NSArray and NSMutableDictionary. It keeps giving me this error:

**ERROR:**

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex(inlove): index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

Could someone please help me and give me and idea why i'm getting this error?

**CODE:**

```
NSMutableDictionary *LicenceDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSArray *LicenceValuesArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[fileContent componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]];

for (NSString *Arrayobject in LicenceValuesArray) {
   if (strlen([Arrayobject UTF8String]) > 3) {
      NSArray *tempArray = [Arrayobject componentsSeparatedByString(angry)" = "];
      [LicenceDictionary setObject:tempArray[1] forKey:tempArray[0]];
   }
}
```

**FILE CONTENT:**

```
CFBundleVersion = 1.100
PortalURL = value
SpineURL = value
Authactivate = value
Authvalidate = value
Authlogout = value
RoleSelection = value
RoleSelectionURL = value
CertificateIssuer = value
SpineSessionPersistance = 0
CardRemovalPersistance = 0
LockScreenAppInactive = 0
PinchZoom = 0
LoggingSupport = 0
LogoutTimer = 90
ScreenLockTimer = 60
ScreenBlankTimer = 30
ProductName = MIA
LoggingLevel = ERROR_LOG
LoggingNumber = 0
LoggingDuration = 1
UpdateType = SILENT
InjectJavaScript = 0
JavaScriptToExecute = value
CustomerLicensed = value
ExpiryMinute = 0
ExpiryHour = 0
ExpiryDay = 31
ExpiryMonth = 10
ExpiryYear = 2014
ReadOnly = 0
Audit = 1
RemoteLogURL = value
SkipCard = 0
Signature = e8ZLMxVouwGs1CSosug3NQGmq9b7TAlraPXDFQocJpw9XNmVcquFme+p5GYVUUZ7waz/33PRX1uV7ECT6z8IK/dcqie4QcVVrC1RO7OSZx71K4QGBtRSaskA2qjSqoMkVGiqDdGwyAmFP66Y8LPW49Lrh7h3tIHwNvdMovajo40=
```

Comment: Add `NSAssert([tempArray length] == 2, @"Oops");` *after* the `NSArray *tempArray =` line and see if that fires (alternatively use a debugger and break on the line *after* and check the array).  You are assuming it contains two objects and it probably doesn't

Comment: Your code assumes `tempArray` has at least 2 objects but it only has one.

Comment: BTW - why are you using `strlen` to check the length of `ArrayObject`? Just do: `if (ArrayObject.length)`. And please use proper naming standards. Only class names should start with uppercase. Method and variable names should start with lowercase.

Comment: @Droppy The NSAssert fires, but i had to use NSAssert([ArrayObject length] == 2, @"Oops"); instead of NSAssert([tempArray length] == 2, @"Oops");

Comment: @rmaddy tempArray[1] is the second value in my file, tempArray[0] is the first value in my file. I'm accessing the values from my file content

Comment: @Chris No, that is not true. `tempArray[0]` is the part before the ` = ` text of a single line and `tempArray[1]` is the part after the ` = ` of the same line. The problem is that there won't be a `tempArray[1]` if the line doesn't contain the text ` = `.

Comment: @rmaddy That's what i'm doing and there is a value after the '='

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add guard code, to ensure the conditions you expect are, in fact, true.  You cannot *assume* something is true just because you want it to be:

```
NSArray *tempArray = [Arrayobject componentsSeparatedByString:@" = "];
if ([tempArray count] == 2) {
    [LicenceDictionary setObject:tempArray[1] forKey:tempArray[0]];
}
```

Also, this:

```
if (strlen([Arrayobject UTF8String]) > 3) {
```

should be:

```
if ([Arrayobject length] > 3) {
```

and this:

```
NSArray *LicenceValuesArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[fileContent  componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]];
```

should be:

```
NSArray *LicenceValuesArray = [fileContent componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

Comment: This got rid of the error thanks, i just have to get the values out of the file again.

Comment: My mistake, there was an error in my server side causing an error in the file content.